# web tab not showing in community builder

Tags: community

i am not able to show web tab in community builder.Can we show web tabs as lightning component in community builder??I can see the web tab in lightning experience but not in community builder

Answer (score 0):

Web Tabs aren't supported in Community Builder. If you are just looking for ways to link an external page in your Community and if you don't need to use Merge Fields in Web Tab, you can use a Navigation Menu with External Link. Would that work for your use case?

Comment: i am using merge expression in my web tab code.